# How to define MultiDex and ProGuard rules in order to prevent "NoClassDefFoundError" in Android using GooglePlus login?

Tags: android, google-plus, proguard, android-multidex

My game has an `GooglePlus` button to let users login with Google. After pressing the button, it shows a popup that contains user's Google accounts. After selecting one of them, app crashes.

This crash shows up after I upgraded all Google Play dependencies from version `10.2.1` to `16.0.0`. My game uses both `MultiDex` and `ProGuard`.

Probably, I need to add rules in `multidex`'s keep and `proguard`'s config files. I tried my best but couldn't find a solution.

Here are logs:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/plus/internal/zzg;
       at com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.zzh.createServiceInterface(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzf.zzm(Unknown Source:17)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.zza(Unknown Source:12)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.zzo(Unknown Source:11)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source:48)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)

Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.zzg
       at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(VMClassLoader.java)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
       at com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.zzh.createServiceInterface(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzf.zzm(Unknown Source:17)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.zza(Unknown Source:12)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.zzo(Unknown Source:11)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source:48)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)

Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/plus/zza;
       at com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.zzh.createServiceInterface(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzf.zzm(Unknown Source:17)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.zza(Unknown Source:12)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.zzo(Unknown Source:11)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source:48)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)


Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.plus.zza" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mobile.example.android-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.mobile.example.android-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.mobile.example.android-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
       at com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.zzh.createServiceInterface(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzf.zzm(Unknown Source:17)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.zza(Unknown Source:12)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.zzo(Unknown Source:11)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source:48)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

**Google's documentation says that below:**

> **Note:** ProGuard directives are included in the Play services client
>   libraries to preserve the required classes. The Android Plugin for
>   Gradle automatically appends ProGuard configuration files in an AAR
>   (Android ARchive) package and appends that package to your ProGuard
>   configuration. During project creation, Android Studio automatically
>   creates the ProGuard configuration files and build.gradle properties
>   for ProGuard use. To use ProGuard with Android Studio, you must enable
>   the ProGuard setting in your build.gradle buildTypes. For more
>   information, see the ProGuard guide.

Any suggestions?